# Caffe output layer number accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I've modified the Caffe [MNIST example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt) to classify 3 classes of image. One thing I noticed was that if I specify the number of output layers as 3, then my test accuracy drops horribly - down to the low 40% range. However, if I +1 and have 4 output layers, the result is in the 95% range.
I added an extra class of images to my dataset (so 4 classes) and noticed the same thing - if the number of output layers were the same as the number of classes, then the result was horrible, if it was the same +1, then it worked really well.

```
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
```

Does anyone know why this is? I've noticed that when I use the model I train with the [C++ example code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp) on an image from my test set then it will complain that I've told it that there are 4 classes present and I've only supplied labels for 3 in my labels file. If I invent a label and add it to the file, I can get the program to run, but then it just returns one of the classes with a probability of 1.0 no matter what image I give it.

Comment: during training, what labels are you using? 1,2,3 or 0,1,2 ?

Comment: With the first group I trained it with 1, 2, 3 and when I added the extra class of images I made that a 0 so it was 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: You must train with 0,1,2 - because labels are used as indices into the output probability vector. So, if you have 3 outputs the labels must be 0,1,2.

Comment: Ah that's fixed the problem, thanks again!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is important to notice that when fine-tuning and/or changing the number of labels the input labels **must** always start from 0, as they are used as indices into the output probability vector when computing the loss.
Thus, if you have

```
 inner_product_params {
   num_output: 3
 }
```

You must have training labels 0,1 and 2 only.

If you use `num_output: 3` with labels 1,2,3 caffe is unable to represent label 3 and in fact has a redundant line corresponding to label 0 that is left unused.
As you observed, when changing to `num_output: 4` caffe is again able to represent label 3 and the results improved, but still you have an unused row in the parameters matrix.

Comment: is it also the case for regression? I have 4 classes in my regression problem, but i used only one output neuron. Is it ok? You can see my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756886/counting-with-regression-in-caffe-training-loss-reducing-but-predicted-values-r?noredirect=1#comment66825237_39756886  Can you kindly guide me whats the real problem?