# Testing a regression network in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am trying to count objects in an image using Alexnet.

I have currently images containing 1, 2, 3 or 4 objects per image. For initial checkup, I have 10 images per class. For example in training set I have:

```
image  label
image1  1
image2  1
image3  1
...
image39 4
image40 4
```

I used imagenet create script to create a lmdb file for this dataset. Which successfully converted my set of images to lmdb.
Alexnet, as an example is converted to a regression model for learning the number of objects in the image by introducing EucledeanLosslayer instead of Softmax Layer. As suggested by many. The rest of the network is the same.

However, despite doing all the above, when I run the model, I received only zeros as output during testing phase(shown below). It did not learn any thing. However, the training loss decreased continuously in each iteration.

I don't understand what mistakes I have made. Can anybody guide me why the predicted values are always 0? And how can I check the regressed values in testing phase, so that to check how many samples are correct and what's the value for each of my image?

The predicted and the actual label of the test dataset is given as :

```
I0928 17:52:45.585160 18302 solver.cpp:243] Iteration 1880, loss = 0.60498
I0928 17:52:45.585212 18302 solver.cpp:259]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.60498 (* 1 = 0.60498 loss)
I0928 17:52:45.585225 18302 solver.cpp:592] Iteration 1880, lr = 1e-06
I0928 17:52:48.397922 18302 solver.cpp:347] Iteration 1900, Testing net (#0)
I0928 17:52:48.499543 18302 accuracy_layer.cpp:88] Predicted_Value: 0 Actual Label: 1
I0928 17:52:48.499641 18302 accuracy_layer.cpp:88] Predicted_Value: 0 Actual Label: 2
I0928 17:52:48.499660 18302 accuracy_layer.cpp:88] Predicted_Value: 0 Actual Label: 3
I0928 17:52:48.499681 18302 accuracy_layer.cpp:88] Predicted_Value: 0 Actual Label: 4
...
```

Note: I also created hdf5 format files in-order to have floating labels, i.e. 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0. However, when i changed data layer to HDF5 type, i can not crop the image for data-augmentation as being done in alexnet with lmdb layer, as well as normalization. I used the script given on "https://github.com/nikogamulin/caffe-utils/blob/master/hdf5/demo.m" for hdf5 data and followed his steps for using it in my model.

I have updated last layers as such:

```
layer {
   name: "fc8reg"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "fc7"
   top: "fc8reg"
   param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
   }
   param {
     lr_mult: 2
     decay_mult: 0
   }
   inner_product_param {
   num_output: 1
   weight_filler {
       type: "gaussian"
       std: 0.01
   }
   bias_filler {
       type: "constant"
       value: 0
   }
   }
 }
 layer {
   name: "accuracy"
   type: "Accuracy"
   bottom: "fc8reg"
   bottom: "label"
   top: "accuracy"
   include {
     phase: TEST
   }
 }
 layer {
   name: "loss"
   type: "EuclideanLoss"
   bottom: "fc8reg"
   bottom: "label"
   top: "loss"
 }
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to the alexnet?

Comment: @AHA I added a euclideonloss layer for regression purpose. And removed softmax layers.

Comment: And also the final output is just 1, as i have one value for each image.

Comment: Please post the final layers of your network. Something doesn't look right.

Comment: @AHA you can check now, I have updated the question by adding last fully connected layer, and loss layer. I will appreciate your fast reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accuracy always 1 Caffe Regression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719915/accuracy-always-1-caffe-regression)

Comment: @Shai not exactly, as his accuracy is always one where as my accuracy is always 0. :) and i used accuracy layer just for printing the predictions otherwise i know it is not needed in regression problems.

Comment: @Shai how can i see the actual calculated value in the fc8reg value during test compare to the label of the image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @khan isn't it the `"loss"` value?

Comment: @Shai I appologize i am a bit confuse. Loss is the difference, Am i right? Not the actual value?

Comment: @khan not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125582/discussion-between-khan-and-shai).

Comment: @khan, I am sorry but I am not available for chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without judging whether your network diverged or not, the obvious mistake you have made is that you shouldn't use a `Accuracy` layer to test a regression network. It is only for  testing a classification network trained by a `SoftmaxWithLoss` Layer.

In fact, given an image for a network, the `Accuracy` layer in the network will always sort its input array(here it is `bottom: "fc8reg"`) and choose the index of the maximal value in the array as the predicted label by default.

Since `num_output == 1` in `fc8reg` layer, `accuracy` layer will always predict index 0 for the input image as its predicted label as you have seen.

At last, you can use a `EuclideanLoss` layer to test your regression network. This [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39720541/6281477) may also give you some hint.

---

If you are to print and calculate the regressed values after training, and count the accuracy of the regression network, you can simply write a `RegressionAccuracy` layer like [**this**](https://gist.github.com/knsong/082f449e98ce168d85c050b15e8b2e88).

Or, if your target label only has 4 discrete values `{1,2,3,4}`, you can still train a classification network for your task.

Comment: i agree that accuracy layer is not needed for regression. I was just using it for predicting whats the output of the network. I checked the similar problem you mentioned as well. However, now my question is, how can i check the regressed values in testing phase, so that to check how many samples are correct and whats the value for each of my image?

Comment: @khan I have update my answer for your new question.

Comment: let me check again as i am receiving an error.. May be it was this.

Comment: Now it works, However there are two points in it. first if i use seperate euclideanloss layer in trianing and this layer in testing, it gives error. Second if i use only this layer for both training and testing than in training the predicted values are even floating. But in testing the predicted values are always 0. Do you think it is not yet trained properly or do we have to change some variables in this new layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125613/discussion-between-dale-song-and-khan).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, everything is correct, but your network is not converging, which is not a rare hapenning. Your network is actually converging to zero outputs!
Maybe most of your samples have 0 as their label.

Also don't forget to include the loss layer only during TRAIN; otherwise, it will learn on test data as wel.

Comment: AFAIK, during TEST phase there is no backprop, so there should be no problem having loss layer for TEST phase: it will only report test loss, but will not update weights (=no learning on test data).