# Caffe: Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (10 vs. 60) Number of labels must match number of predictions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, regression, caffe

I am trying to fine tune Alexnet for a multi-label regression task. For this  I have replaced the last layer producing 1000-label output (for image classification task) to 6 label output which provides me with 6 floats. I replaced the last layers [as mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/denoza/1683e16828b16449fd3919ba5f9873ef).

My training data is prepared in `h5` format and is shaped as (11000, 3, 544, 1024) for `data` and (11000, 1, 6) for `labels`. While retraining the weights of Alexnet in Caffe library, I get the following error:

```
I1013 10:50:49.759560  3107 net.cpp:139] Memory required for data: 950676640

I1013 10:50:49.759562  3107 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer accuracy_retrain

I1013 10:50:49.759567  3107 net.cpp:86] Creating Layer accuracy_retrain

I1013 10:50:49.759568  3107 net.cpp:408] accuracy_retrain <- fc8_fc8_retrain_0_split_0

I1013 10:50:49.759572  3107 net.cpp:408] accuracy_retrain <- label_data_1_split_0

I1013 10:50:49.759575  3107 net.cpp:382] accuracy_retrain -> accuracy

F1013 10:50:49.759587  3107 accuracy_layer.cpp:31] Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (10 vs. 60) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if label axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.
```

My Batchsize for both training and testing phases is `10`. The error arises in the testing phase, possibly in the `accuracy` layer [Complete Error Log here](https://gist.github.com/denoza/35e8904986451171fc8c5bf3817ab76e). I am not sure why this problem arises, might be my `label` is misshaped. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Seems like the `accuracy` layer is only used for classification tasks along with `SoftmaxWithLoss` layer. As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756886/testing-a-regression-network-in-caffe), the `EuclideanLoss` can be used to test the regression network.